# I have few questions relating to the null safety feature which is offered by dart or flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have few questions with regards to the null safety feature offered by Flutter/Dart.

1. Is it mandatory to make use of the null safety feature for flutter projects?
2. If I don't make use of the null safety feature, will I still be able to make use of all the existing and latest flutter widgets, with all the latest functionality they have got to offer? What I mean to say is, is there any specific functionality that is only available when the null safety feature is enabled.
3. What would be the major disadvantages, I could encounter, apart from the null check, if I don't make use of the null safety feature for the flutter projects?
4. Even if the code is correct, I find that the null safety feature would keep throwing the null check operator error, which is very annoying.

Could anyone please help with answering my queries, as I find this null safety to be very confusing and annoying. I did go through few videos but still, I'm not convinced.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Null safety can be overridden
2. Yes, you should still be able to make use of the new flutter widgets.
3. If you use don't null-safety, it will be slower
4. This is more like a statement than a question

[Understanding Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is it mandatory to make use of the null safety feature for flutter projects?

No, you can still use the previous SDK constraints to not comply with NULL safety rules

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
```

---

> 2. If I don't make use of the null safety feature, will I still be able to make use of all the existing and latest flutter widgets, with all the latest functionality they have got to offer? What I mean to say is, is there any specific functionality that is only available when the null safety feature is enabled.

Yes provided you set the environment as mentioned above or you can also specify at the top of your Dart file to disable null checks for that file.

```
// @dart=2.9
```

---

> 3. What would be the major disadvantages, I could encounter, apart from the null check, if I don't make use of the null safety feature for the flutter projects?

Note that eliminating null is not a goal. There’s nothing wrong with null. On the contrary, it’s really useful to be able to represent the absence of a value. Sometimes indicating absence is really important. It is not null that is bad, it is **having null go where you don’t expect it** that causes problems. So to avoid such crashes Dart migrated to Sound NULL Safety.

---

> 4. Even if the code is correct, I find that the null safety feature would keep throwing the null check operator error, which is very annoying.

You can definitely make some types NULL with the handy `?` null-aware operator. For eg, you can make your `String` as `String?` provided indicating absence is really important and it won't cause problems in the future program flow.

Adding `!` (null assertion operator )after any expression is equivalent to saying that "Hey Dart ! trust me that this value will never be null".

Initially, it might trouble you a lot. But remember, it's worthwhile migrating your apps to Sound Null Safety.

---

**Further Reading** -

1. https://dart.dev/null-safety
2. [Why NULL Safety ?](https://youtu.be/tP9TcrUZoIs)

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
class Animal {
  Dog dog;
}

class Dog{
 String name;
}
```

Operator "!":
If you allow it to be null and allow it to throw an exception.

```
main(){
  Animal animal = Animal();
  print(animal.dog!.name); // throw exception dog is null
}
```

Operator "?"
If you want it will do nothing if the current parameter is null

```
main(){
  Animal animal = Animal();
  print(animal.dog?.name); // output emplty
}
```

You can give a replacement value of the parameter if the current value is null

```
main(){
  Animal animal = Animal();
  print(animal.dog?.name ?? "The kiki"); // output "The kiki"
}
```

The function required not null

```
fun getName(String name){
 print(name); 
}

main(){
   String? name = null;
  getName(name); // throw an exception because the required the name argument is not null
}
```

The function allows null

```
fun getName(String? name){
 print(name); 
}

main(){
   String? name = null;
  getName(name); // output null
}
```

Null safety in the Constructor

Use required operator

```
class Animal {
  String? name;
  String age;
  Animal({this.name,required this.age}); // The age argument not allowed to be null so you must add the required operator first
}
```

or use positional arguments constructor

```
class Animal {
      String? name;
      String age;
      Animal(this.age, {this.name}); // age is positional argument
    }
```

or use default value constructor

```
class Animal {
      String? name;
      String age;
      Animal({this.name, this.age = "18" }); // age is positional argument
    }
```